# A command to create an environment with a command

Tags: macros, environments

I'm trying to create a command to create an environment that define a command that contains the name of the environment and an argument.

`#1` is the argument of `createEnv`,
`##1` is the argument of the environment.
So, I thought that `###1` will contains the argument of the command `\skill` but I got errors.

Is is even possible to have a 3 nested layers of command ?

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\createEnv}{m}{
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{#1}{m}{
        \NewDocumentCommand{\skill}{m}{
             #1 : ###1 ///
        }
    }{
    }
}

\createEnv{Foo}
\createEnv{Goo}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of `#` double for each layer, so here

`#1` is the argument to `\createEnv`

`##1` is the mandatory argument to the `#1` env

`####1` is the mandatory argument to `\skill`.

You have `###` (three) and that is an error.